# C return of multiple values

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

So i want to return this

```
monsterstat[4] = {monsterhp, monsteratkmin,monsteratkmax,monstermax};
return monsterstat;
```

this is possible reciving the value with another array with the same size?
Obs :

```
    double monsterstat[4];
```

Comment: Looks like you want to create a `struct` to hold these values.

Comment: you cannot return an array however a double pointer can be returned pointing to the base address

Comment: If you want to modify values in some array, pass it as an argument to the function that will modify it and don't return any value at all. No weird, completely unnecessary structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return in C an array of values (you'll just return a pointer to that array).

You may consider either returning a `struct`, e.g. declare

```
 struct monsterstat_st {
     double m_hp, m_kmin, m_kmax, m_max;
 };
 typedef struct monsterstat_st monsterstat_t;
```

in a header (or before your function). Then your function which I suppose is named `compute_monster_stat` might be

```
  monsterstat_t compute_monster_stat(double x) {
     monsterstat_t res;
     res.m_hp = compute_hp(x); // or some computation
     res.m_kmin = compute_kmin(x); // or some other computation
     res.m_kmax = compute_kmax(x); // or something more
     res.m_max = compute_max(x); // or your own code
     return res;
  }
```

and you'll call it like e.g.

```
  monsterstat_t mystat = compute_monster_stat(something);
```

However, notice that (at least on Linux x86-64 according to its [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf)) the data would go on the stack (but if you had only 2 members it could go thru registers; details are very specific).

Alternatively, and very often in C code, you pass a pointer to the computed data, so code

```
  int computed_monster_stat(monsterstat_t* ptr, double data) {
     if (ptr && happy_with(data)) {
        ptr->m_hp = compute_hp(data);
        ptr->m_kmin = compute_kmin(data);
        ptr->m_kmax = compute_kmax(data);
        ptr->m_max = compute_max(data);
        return 1;
     } else return 0;
  }
```

that you would use like

```
  monsterstat_t s;
  memset (&s, 0, sizeof(s)); // easy way to clear the data
  if (computed_monster_stat (&s, data)) {
     // do something with s.m_kmin etc....
  } else {
     // unhappy
  }
```

A more concrete exemple is given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) or [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) syscalls on Linux.

Alternatively, return a [pointer to] some [heap allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28programming%29) `struct` or array (so call `malloc` inside your function), with e.g. the *documented convention* that the caller of your function has to `free` it. Beware of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) etc etc....

BTW, take several hours to **read a good *C* programming book**, and look into and **study some free software** (e.g. on [freecode](https://freecode.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/),  [github](https://github.com/) and many other places) similar to what you want to code.

Comment: Thanks but how i can access and chance the values in  the struct?

Comment: I suggest you to take several hours to read a good book on C programming. We simply don't have the time and patience to teach all of it! Then, look at some existing free software and study its code for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

## Using a struct

Create a `struct` that holds all your fields.

```
typedef struct MonsterStat {
   int monsterhp;
   int monsteratkmin;
   int monsteratkmax;
   int monstermax;
} MonsterStat;
```

Now declare a variable

```
MonsterStat monsterstat;
```

To initialize member variables, there are several ways

```
// In order
MonsterStat monsterstat = {60, 12, 14, 60};

// Specifying fields

MonsterStat monsterstat = {
  .monsterhp = 60,
  .monsteratkmin = 12,
  .monsteratkmax = 14,
  .monstermax = 60
};
```

### Using the struct in a function

```
// Level up the monster
MonsterStat level_up(MonsterStat monsterstat){
  monsterstat.monsterhp += 10;
  monsterstat.monstermax += 12;
  return monsterstat;
}

// Return a default monster
MonsterStat default(){
  MonsterStat monsterstat = {60, 12, 14, 60};
  return monsterstat;
}
```

## Returning arrays

The only way to "return" an array (properly) is to receive a pointer to an allocated array and change the elements. Arrays themselves can't be passed. Only pointers are really passed (that point to the arrays in memory).

You can of course do this really wrong, allocate an array in the function, and return a pointer to that array. You've now opened yourself up to a stack overflow (no pun here, this is the namesake of the site).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to pass the address of a place to store each value:

```
void get_monstrstat(int *pmonsterhp, int *pmonsteratkmin, int *pmonsteratkmax, int *pmonstermax)
{
    *pmonsterhp = monsterhp;
    // … similar for the remaining items
}
```